# Posting JSON object via AJAX to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I have tried different methods that have been posted on this site, but nothing seems to work.
I want to create a clothing site (a personal project). The products on the site have their own class, that is built like this:

```
 public class Product
 {
      public string ProductName { get; set; }
      public string ProductPrice { get; set; }

      public int Quantity { get; set; }
 }
```

The shopping cart is another class that will contain a list of `Product` objects and this one is built like this:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public string ClientAddress { get; set; }

    public string ClientMail { get; set; }
}
```

I created an API Controller class and thought that would solve the problem. It looks like this:

```
[Route("api/Shopping")]
[ApiController]
public class ShoppingCartController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ShoppingCart Save([FromBody] ShoppingCart s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

In my JavaScript code I create my JSON object and try to post it like this:

```
 var orderB = document.getElementById("orderB");
    orderB.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
        var inputMail = document.getElementById("inputMail").value;
        var auxArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < productsAux.length; i++) {
            auxArray[i] = { "productName": productsAux[i].titlu, "productPrice": productsAux[i].pret, "quantity": localStorage.getItem(productsAux[i].titlu)};
        }

        var shoppingCart = {
            productList: auxArray,
            clientName: inputName,
            clientAddress: inputAddress,
            clientMail: inputMail
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),
            url: "api/shopping/save",
            contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
             }).done(function (res) {
            alert(res);
        });
```

After I push the order button on my page I expect to see the alert pop-up with the callback result which I suppose is the `ShoppingCart` object that is created using the JSON that I send.

Comment: So...what doesn't work? Did you check the browser console to see if there's any errors? Did you check what's actually being posted? We need some more details.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I do not have any errors in my browser console.The thing is I got stuck at this step, I formed my JSON object and now I'm trying to pass it to my Controller in order to create my C# object and then later add it to my database.Where can I see what's being posted?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your controller method.

Comment: @ballonDor, run your api in debugging mode (F5 in VS) and place breakpoint at opening brace. By the way, you don't need to mark your parameter with `[FromBody]`. If action methods accept complex objects as parameter WebAPI uses registered MediaTypeFormatters for binding. Media type formatter for json content type  is included by default in WebAPI.

Comment: @Ryan I put the breakpoint and ran it, but it does not seem to show anything useful in my debugging console.

Comment: @Ryan I re-edited the code a little bit

Comment: @ballonDor in your browser, chrome or edge, hit F12 so you can see the console. Bring up the Network tab. There, you should be able to see the exact object being sent to your controller, if it's even getting that far. I echo the notion to remove FromBody.

Comment: Also, just for giggles, remove the List / array stuff and just start with strings. I have had fun issues with how it tries to represent and serialize Lists. See if it works without that.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I opened the Network tab and I got this:  I got a 404 (kind of expected that) , the name of the method 'save' , a type of 'xhr' and a size of 45B.Now in the request payload I can see my JSON object.But in the response tab I have nothing going on. And also the 'FromBody' is removed.

Comment: @ballonDor, now remove last url segment in ajax call. Url should look as `"api/shopping`. By default WebApi specifies calling method by HTTP Method type (GET, POST, etc.) ,  if no routing explicit specified.

Comment: What Ryan said there.

Comment: @Ryan Unfortunately I still get the 404 even after changing the url.

Comment: @ballonDor, change your ContentType parameter to this: `application/json;charset=utf-8`.   Please note semicolon was added. Url should be `api/shopping`.

Comment: @Ryan changed it still the same result

Comment: @Ryan At this point I don't even know what's wrong.

Comment: @ballonDor. Try to get rid off ContentType option at all in your ajax call. As i know, jquery  is able to compute it. Well, have no any other ideas...

Comment: Managed to solve the issue.Thank you guys for the help.I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I opened the Network tab and I got this: I got a 404 (kind of
> expected that) , the name of the method 'save' , a type of 'xhr' and a
> size of 45B.

The 404 error obviously means ***the url/routing is wrong***. Here to solve it ,you have two ways to achieve.

### First way:

You can **change url to "api/shopping" in ajax** as follow:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),
                url: "api/shopping",
                contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
            }).done(function (res) {
                alert(res);
            })
```

### Second way:

You can change the path name
of `Save` action  by **[Attribute routing with Http verb attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes)** as follow:

```
            [Route("api/Shopping")]
            [ApiController]
            public class ShoppingCartController : ControllerBase
            {
                [HttpPost("Save")]
                public ShoppingCart Save([FromBody] ShoppingCart s)
                {
            
                    return s;
                }
            }
```

### Update

According to your comment, in addition to the above updates, you also need to modify the **routing** settings as follows:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
 });
```

Debug result:

[image]

Comment: Tried both of these methods and none seems to work.

Comment: @ballonDor, please provide us with your controller code in its entirety, as well as the Configure method in your starup.cs file.

Comment: `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
            });
        }`

Comment: The controller code is just the same code that I posted before.Also I mapped the Controllers like this: `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });`

Comment: @ballonDor, ok, it's the problem of your routing set, I have updated my reply.

Comment: @ballonDor, I think of another thing. Are your api code and ajax code in the same project? Or do they represent two projects?

Comment: They are in the same project.

Comment: I managed to solve something (that's what I think).It now routes to localhost//ShoppingCart but I don't remember routing to this page.

Comment: @ballonDor, so ,did you solve it？ In fact, I am also testing in the same project. You can change the routing settings to be exactly the same as mine. I did not have any problems with the test here. Are you a core mvc project?

Comment: Ok I modified the routing settings and it routes correctly now.My concern now is how can I verify on the server side that what I've sent through my JSON is correct?Is there a way to console log the data that I've received or maybe send it back to client and console log it in the browser console?

Comment: @ballonDor, you can directly use the `F12` tool in the browser to monitor the transmitted data in the `Network ` tab. The specific operation is updated in my answer using animated pictures.
If the data can be passed successfully, you can also debug the data of the `s ` variable directly by breaking the point in the `save` action.

Comment: In my case it just doesn't route to the "api/shopping".When I click the button it just refreshes my page.Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am not using the Index page?This is killing me slowly :D

Comment: @ballonDor,In fact, there are many reasons for these problems. I suggest you update the question and provide us with all current relevant codes for reference.

Comment: I modified my project into an MVC one.It wasn't an MVC.Managed to route to the api/shopping but in my case I don't get back that object in the request payload.

Comment: I mean the data is sent but the productList in my case is null.Everything is sent okay.I ran it with the debugger.Also im redirected correctly to "api/shopping" but I get this in my page: `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|ad581984-450c6546501818fa."}`

Comment: Managed to solve the problem everything works fine.Just as expected thank you so much for the help!!!Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For those coming on later, I would suggest checking that your types are correct on both ends. For instance, if your JS is posting a byte array and C# tries to convert it to an int, the whole object (not just that prop) will be null.

This has caught me many a time.